# got problem with the websocket with python/django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Im trying to make notification for my project but Im having problem with my DB and api
first Im using postgreSQL but my models.py does not upload on db
second so I made db on admin page and it actually uploaded on my db so I checked on my developer's tool, they did actually brought API but empty
so I need help on those 2 issues

1. can't upload notification models on pgadmin when I leave a comment on my project
2. when I passively upload data at db on admin it worked but still API is empty

here are some of my project works
Thank you

views.py

```py
class NotificationCreate (APIView):
    # 로그인 한 유저만 가능
    permission_classes = [IsTokenValid]  # IsTokenValid 권한을 적용

    def post(self, request):
        print("Notification_post")
        content = request.data.get('content')
        notifications = Notifications(content=content)
        notifications.save()
        serializer = NotificationSerializer(notifications)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
    def get(self,request):
        print("Notification_get")
        notifications = Notifications.objects.all()
        serializer = NotificationSerializer(notifications, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
class CommentCreateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsTokenValid]

    def post(self, request, study_id, story_id):
        print("Comment_post")
        # 사용자로부터 댓글 내용을 받아옵니다.
        content = request.data.get('content')
        article_type = request.data.get('article_type')  # 'study' 또는 'story'
        article_id = request.data.get('article_id')  # 게시물의 ID
        user = get_user_from_token(request)

        # 실제로 댓글을 생성하고 데이터베이스에 저장하는 코드 (예시)
        # Comment 모델이 있다고 가정하고 사용자 입력을 활용하여 댓글을 생성합니다.
        # 새로운 댓글을 데이터베이스에 저장하고 study_id와 연결합니다.
        new_comment = Notifications.objects.create(content=content, category_article=article_type, article_num=article_id, user=user)

        if article_type == 'study':
            try:
                study = Study.objects.get(id=article_id)
                story.comments.add(new_comment)

                # 작성자와 댓글 작성자가 다를 경우에만 실행
                if study.user != user:
                    study.comments.add(new_comment)
                    
                    # 알림 생성 및 저장
                    category_article = "study"
                    article_num = study_id
                    category_likecomment = "comment"
                    content = "새로운 댓글이 달렸습니다!"
                    created_at = datetime.now()

                    Notifications.objects.create(
                        user_id=user.id,
                        category_article=category_article,
                        article_num=article_num,
                        category_likecomment=category_likecomment,
                        content=content,
                        created_at=created_at
                    )

                    return JsonResponse({'success': 'Comment and notification created successfully'})
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Cannot add comment to your own study'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            except Study.DoesNotExist:
                # 해당 ID에 해당하는 Study 게시물이 존재하지 않는 경우의 처리
                pass
        # article_type이 'story'인 경우 Story 모델에 댓글 추가
        elif article_type == 'story':
            #작성자와 댓글 작성자가 다를경우 실행
            try:
                story = Post.objects.get(id=article_id)
                story.comments.add(new_comment)
            # 작성자와 댓글 작성자가 다를 경우에만 실행
                if story.user != user:
                    story.comments.add(new_comment)
                    
                    # 알림 생성 및 저장
                    category_article = "post"
                    article_num = story_id
                    category_likecomment = "comment"
                    content = "새로운 댓글이 달렸습니다!"
                    created_at = datetime.now()

                    Notifications.objects.create(
                        user_id=user.id,
                        category_article=category_article,
                        article_num=article_num,
                        category_likecomment=category_likecomment,
                        content=content,
                        created_at=created_at
                    )

                    return JsonResponse({'success': 'Comment and notification created successfully'})
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Cannot add comment to your own study'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            except Study.DoesNotExist:
                # 해당 ID에 해당하는 Study 게시물이 존재하지 않는 경우의 처리
                pass

        # 알림 생성 및 저장
        # category_article = "study"  # 또는 "story" (댓글이 달린 게시글의 유형)
        # article_num = study_id  # 댓글이 달린 게시글의 ID
        # category_likecomment = "comment"
        # content = "새로운 댓글이 달렸습니다!"
        # created_at = datetime.now()  # 현재 시간을 사용하여 알림 생성 시간 기록

        # Notifications.objects.create(
        #     user_id=user.id,
        #     category_article=category_article,
        #     article_num=article_num,
        #     category_likecomment=category_likecomment,
        #     content=content,
        #     created_at=created_at
        # )

        # 알림 정보를 클라이언트에게 반환
        # return JsonResponse({'success': 'Comment and notification created successfully'})
        
class LikeView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsTokenValid]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Like_post")
        # 좋아요를 누른 사용자의 ID를 가져옵니다.
        user = get_user_from_token(request)

        # article_type이 'study'이면 Study 모델에서, 'story'이면 Story 모델에서 게시물을 가져옵니다.
        article_type = request.data.get('article_type')
        article_id = request.data.get('article_id')

        if article_type == 'study':
            try:
                study = Study.objects.get(id=article_id)
                # Study 모델에서 게시물을 가져왔으므로 이를 사용할 수 있습니다.
            except Study.DoesNotExist:
                # 해당 ID에 해당하는 Study 게시물이 존재하지 않는 경우의 처리
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Study not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        elif article_type == 'story':
            try:
                story = Post.objects.get(id=article_id)
                # Story 모델에서 게시물을 가져왔으므로 이를 사용할 수 있습니다.
            except Post.DoesNotExist:
                # 해당 ID에 해당하는 Story 게시물이 존재하지 않는 경우의 처리
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Story not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            # 유효하지 않은 article_type 값에 대한 처리
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid article_type'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # 좋아요를 생성합니다.
        Like.objects.create(user_id=user.id, study=study)
        
        # 알림을 생성합니다.
        Notifications.objects.create(
            user_id=user.id,
            category_article='like',
            article_num=article_id,
            category_likecomment='like',  # 좋아요인 경우에는 'like'로 설정
            content='Someone liked your post.',
        )

        return JsonResponse({'success': 'Like created successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

consumers.py

```py
class NotificationsConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        # 사용자가 웹소켓에 연결되면 모든 사용자에게 알림을 전송합니다.
        self.user_group_name = "all_users"

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.user_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()
    # async def connect(self):
    #     self.user = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["user"]
    #     self.user_group_name = f"user_{self.user}"
    #     print("connect complete")
    #     await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.user_group_name, self.channel_name)
    #     await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.user_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def send_notification(self, event):
        notification_message = event["message"]
        notification_type = event.get("type", "notification")  # 이벤트에서 타입을 동적으로 가져옴
        print("noti complete")

        # 메시지 전송
        await self.send(
            text_data=json.dumps({"type": "notification_type", "message": notification_message})
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print("Received message:", text_data)
        if "user_id" in data and "category_likecomment" in data and "created_at" in data:
            user_id = data["user_id"]
            category_likecomment = data["category_likecomment"]
            created_at = data["created_at"]
            count = data.get("count", 0)

         # 저장 로직 추가
            try:
                Notifications.objects.create(user_id=user_id, category_likecomment=category_likecomment, created_at=created_at)
                print("Notification saved successfully")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error saving notification:", str(e))

            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                self.groupname,
                {
                    "type": "share_message",
                    "count": count,
                    "category_likecomment": category_likecomment,
                    "created_at": created_at,
                },
            )

            await self.send(
                text_data=json.dumps({"message": data["message"]})  # 저장된 메시지를 다시 클라이언트에게 전송
            )
        else:
            print("Required fields are missing")

    async def alarm(self, event):
```

alrarm.js

```js
import { UserInfo } from './jwtUserId.js';
// 서버로부터 UserIds를 가져오는 함수

// 웹소켓 연결 및 알림 처리 함수
async function setupWebSocket() {
    console.log('연결')
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/notifications/", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`, // access_token을 헤더에 추가
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        const UserIds = data;

        console.log(data)

        UserIds.forEach(user => {
            let userId = user;// 사용자 ID를 얻어올 수 있는 방법에 따라 userId 값을 설정

            if (userId === null) {
                userId = '1';
                console.log(userId);
            }

            const userObject = UserInfo(accessToken);
            console.log(userId);
            console.log(typeof userId, userId.user, data, userObject.userId);

            if (userId.user == userObject.userId) {

                const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/notifications/${userId.user}/`);
                console.log(userId.user, userObject.userId, "아이디와 사용자아이디가 일치합니다.");


                // 알림 카운트를 업데이트하는 함수
                function updateNotificationCount(count) {
                    console.log(count, ' is checked');
                    const notificationCountElement = document.querySelector('.notify_count');
                    if (notificationCountElement) {
                        notificationCountElement.innerText = count;
                    }
                }
                socket.onopen = function (message) {
                    console.log('open checked');
                }


                socket.onmessage = function (e) {
                    console.log(e, ' is checked');
                    console.log(e.data, ' is checked');
                    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                    const notificationMessage = data['message'];
                    const notificationCount = data['count'];

                    // 알림 메시지를 처리하고 UI 업데이트를 수행
                    const notificationContent = document.querySelector('.notification-content');
                    notificationContent.innerText = notificationMessage;
                    // 알림 모달에 active 클래스 추가하여 화면에 보이게 만듦
                    notificationModal.classList.add('active');
                    // 숫자를 알림 아이콘 위에 업데이트
                    updateNotificationCount(notificationCount);
                };

                // 웹소켓 연결이 닫힐 때의 로직도 추가할 수 있습니다.
                socket.onclose = function (event) {
                    console.log('웹소켓 연결이 닫혔습니다.', event);
                };
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching userIds:', error);
    }
}

// 웹소켓 설정 함수 호출
setupWebSocket();

// 알림 모달의 열기, 닫기 등의 로직을 여기에 추가하세요.
const notificationModal = document.querySelector('.notification-modal');
const notificationCountElement = document.querySelector('.notification-count');
const notificationTrigger = document.querySelector('.notification-trigger');
```

Im trying to make notification for my project but Im having problem with my DB and api
first Im using postgreSQL but my models.py does not upload on db
second so I made db on admin page and it actually uploaded on my db so I checked on my developer's tool, they did actually brought API but empty